# $\mu(A\backslash B) = \mu(A)-\mu(B)$...when does this hold?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have looked seemingly everywhere on this site yet couldn't find an answer to this question: when is it the case that the difference between two sets has a measure equal to the difference in measures (i.e., what conditions will allow $\mu(A\backslash B) = \mu(A)-\mu(B)$ to hold true)?

I don't anticipate a list of all possible situations...however, some cases alongside maybe examples would be extremely helpful. As far as context is concerned, this is simply for the sake of curiosity; not necessarily for any specific proof. I am currently studying Gerald Folland's Real Analysis text.

Comment: If $B\subset A$ and $\mu(A)<\infty$

Comment: @AndrewZhang $\mu(B) < \infty$. $A$ can have infinite measure, we just can't subtract $\infty$ naively.

Comment: It holds true if $B$ is measurable and a subset of $A$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If $B\subset A$, and $\mu(B)<\infty$, then we are OK. This condition is of course more general than $\mu(A)<\infty$

Comment: That's it? Lot less complicated than I was expecting. Thanks all!

Comment: @JAG131 As an aside, when $B$ isn't a subset of $A$ in a given argument, it's a common trick to write $B = (A \cap B) \cup (B \setminus A)$ so you can then cut out the piece of $B$ that actually lies in $A$.

Comment: It's not necessary that $B\subseteq A,$ i.e. $B\setminus A=\emptyset.$ One can have $B\setminus A\neq\emptyset$ as long as $\mu(B\setminus A)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

First assume that $\mu(A)<\infty$ and $\mu(B)<\infty$ so that the right hand side is defined.

Then, since $A = (A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B),$ where $A\setminus B$ and $A\cap B$ are disjoint, we have
$
\mu(A) = \mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(A\cap B),
$
i.e.
$$
\mu(A\setminus B)=\mu(A)-\mu(A\cap B).
$$
But we want the second term on the right hand side to be $\mu(B),$ so when is $\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(B)$? Just as above we also have
$$
\mu(B\setminus A) = \mu(B) - \mu(A\cap B)
.
$$
Thus $\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(B)$ exactly when $\mu(B\setminus A)=0.$

We conclude that for sets $A$ and $B$ of finite measure we have $\mu(A\setminus B) = \mu(A)-\mu(B)$ exactly when $\mu(B\setminus A)=0,$ i.e. when $B$ is almost included in $A$.